# Anyone else being hit by traffic on TCP port 11370

Tags: security, firewall, iptables, log-files

I've been watching my logs (Ubuntu 9.10 server) and dunno about any of you but I am getting a ton of traffic from sources like Russia, Romania, etc.. on port 11370 (my iptables are logndrop'ing it. But was just curious).

**Some googling revealed this info:**
http://www.keysigning.org/sks/ -which seems to use port 11370 & 11371

Could that be the service they are scanning for (i don't run it)?

ICS shows this: https://isc.incidents.org/port.html?port=11370

Just curious what you guys think and if anyone has seen this before?  If need be I can post my log on here, but its just a dropped log of TCP port 11370 from various IPs.

Thought it was strange as thats the ONLY Port I seem to repeatedly be hit on (from logs).

I'm running on a Linode (VPS) if that matters to annyone.

Comment: I have to say I'm pretty impressed you actually read  your firewall logs. I don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open (`socat -v tcp-l:11370,reuseaddr -`) this port and watch what goes to it

Alternatively, redirect the traffic somewhere to analyse using `iptables`.

/* Note: comments and votes were for other, shorter formulation */

Comment: Negative captain. Tcpdump would be able to see that traffic even without allowing it in iptables.

Comment: Probably it will be TCP SYNs. I thought he wants to know what service is trying to be accessed. How tcpdump can show the data if connection fails? No connection => no data.

The way without allowing actual connection may be setting up iptables to REDIRECT to some controlled port or DNAT to some other IP which will anonyse the data.

Comment: Vi, I believe you're confused. Tcpdump can show any IP packet that hits the network interface card. A successful TCP handshake is not needed.

Comment: I think Vi's point is that some data won't be sent until a connection is established. Take for example an HTTP request - if you have port 80 blocked, you will never be able to see what it's requesting because the request isn't made until the connection is opened.

Comment: @ErikA Is the actual data that is transmitted by TCP seen in the that packets? I see things like "GET / HTTP/1.1" in the third packet (first is SYN, second is ACK). If connection is rejected or filtered, I can't see what actual data would have been transmitted if the connection were established.

Comment: Ahh, got it. Yes, you're absolutely right, he won't see the actual GET request.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is some new zeroday exploit on a service that runs on that, or a some kind of backdoor rat. checkout http://www.dshield.org/trends.html. Consider offering your firewall logs to them.

If you on your server an want to check if a process is listening on that port just do

netstat -l -p -d | grep 11370

also if you see unknown port numbers doing

cat /etc/services  | grep 11370

come up blank on my machine.

I think (if it's still available) tcpview.exe on windows to do the same job.